# Python rearrange list starting from a certain element

Tags: python, list

I have a python list and an index of an item I want to start a loop on the list starting from the element after my index.
For example I have:

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_index = 2
new_list = [4,5,1,2,3]
```

I am trying to achieve the new list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use list [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1903116), like this

```
>>> original_list, my_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2
>>> original_list[my_index + 1:] + original_list[:my_index + 1]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: For large lists, use itertools.islice

Comment: @fredtantini and `itertools.chain` but this would only help for very huge lists

Comment: An alternative is `list(islice(cycle(original_list), my_index+1, my_index+len(original_list)+1)` but i can't think of a case where this would be useful haha

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) and can use `deque.rotate`.

```
In [70]: original_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [71]: import collections

In [72]: deq = collections.deque(original_list) 
In [77]: deq.rotate(2)
In [78]: deq
Out[78]: deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possibility:

```
>>> olist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print [olist[n-2] for n in xrange(len(olist))]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```